# convert Apache to Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, yii, nginx

How will it look like in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default?
I use nginx/1.6.0

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/ProjectName">
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

I've tried:

```
 location /ProjectName {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /ProjectName/index.php?r=$request_uri;
     }
```

It almost seems to work but if I have are url with questions mark:
 http://ProjectName.dk/Test/site/getPerson?Id=369
I get error?

The question is what else should be added to the nginx conf?

Comment: May be you need `$uri` instead of `$request_uri`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /ProjectName/index.php?r=$query_string;
```

Now it works with questions mark.